# Ethically iffy questions

Tags: discussion

What should be the standard response for people asking questions that seem like they could be for nefarious purposes? Should these be flagged, responded to, or just ignored.

For example, there is one question that sounds an awful lot like someone asking how to use Tor for a botnet. Given the benefit of the doubt, this could be a legitimate question but it feels like it's not something that should be helped with.

Answer (score 1):

*not sure if this is worth an answer, because it is just my opinion!*

well... SE is about asking & answering questions and spreading knowledge, not about policeing others. nevertheless in such a case the problem would also be, that in a global community things which are somewhere (il)legal can quite differ anywhere else! ...and i'm completely against exporting laws or even moral standards! *...you can never know which will get exported. ;-)*

so IMHO if you want to answer a question (and you are in line with your local laws), feel free to answer it!

---

we had a quite similar discussion at *Software Recommendations* some time ago: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2618/9157